# Why is the boundary of a topological space $M$ denoted $\partial M$?

Tags: general-topology, notation

Why is the boundary of a topological space $M$ often denoted $\partial M$?

Is there any connection between boundary and partial derivative?

Comment: See: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46252/is-the-boundary-partial-s-analogous-to-a-derivative